# check method for custom attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, late-binding

I'm not sure why the below method always returns false

```
        // method to check for presence of TestCaseAttribute
    private static bool hasTestCaseAttribute(MemberInfo m)
    {
        foreach (object att in m.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(att.ToString());
            if (att is TestCase.TestCaseAttribute) // also tried if (att is TestCaseAttribute)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

even though the console output looks like this:

```
TestCase.DateAttribute
TestCase.AuthorAttribute
TestCase.TestCaseAttribute
```

What am I missing here?

Edit;  this approach seems to work...

```
  private static bool hasTestCaseAttribute(MemberInfo m)
    {
        if (m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCaseAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
    private static bool hasTestCaseAttribute(MemberInfo m)
    {
        return m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCaseAttribute), true).Any();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool HasCustomAttribute(MethodInfo methodInfo, bool inherit = false)
{
    return methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>(inherit) != null;
}
```

You could use the function above which is much more succinct than your current approach. sa_ddam's snippet works too.

Comment: Thanks ByteBlast!  See my edit on how I incorporated.  Please don't hesitate to comment if you think I should do something different.

Comment: No worries. You don't need the cumbersome `if else statement`. The else is redundant because if the first condition is met the method will `return` returning control to calling address. The function `GetCustomAttributes` already returns a boolean so you don't need any conditional checking at all really. Simply echo the value that function returns like I did in my example.

Comment: You know, I tried that, but still got a false value.  I'm using this method as a check to ensure that the attribute exists in the MethodInfo object before invoking it, so I need to make sure that I can get either a true or false.

Comment: The re-factoring I described should not affect anything like that :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private static bool hasTestCaseAttribute(MethodInfo method)
{    
    object[] customAttributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method, 
                                    typeof(TestCase), true) as TestCase;
    if(customAttributes.Length>0 && customAttributes[0]!=null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
```